# Why is the Bootstrap Modal not opening on page load/open

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried, but I'm lost. How do I get the Modal to open on page load. I belive I have the correct Bootstrap links, in the right place.

But, first, how do I post code?
I keep getting the message about code not formatted properly, when I have copied it directly from dreamweaver, where I have checked and there are no errors. I am very confused.
here's the page link though
https://hisplacehastings.co.uk/index2modaltest.html

thanks.

Comment: The question doesn't include enough information to suggest a solution.  Yet, the problem might be that you are trying to display the modal before the page is completely loaded. See [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

Your site got an error on the console:

```
index2modaltest.html:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at index2modaltest.html:10:5
```

You are trying to use jQuery here and it causes an error of `not defined`.

Basically, you could listen to `DOMContentLoaded` event to show the modal.

So replace this

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

With this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.querySelector('#myModal'));
    modal.show();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it's the only solution that works. Could I ask you how I would get the modal to only show once per session, not when user clicks back to page on same visit?